# C++ Comparing 2 arrays issue?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am reading a list of strings from a text file and inputting it into an array. Then i'm asking the user for another list of strings to put into a new array and I want to compare the 2 strings and output the ones that are the same (so an intersection of 2 arrays) I get an Unhandled exception at 0x0F6508AB and it says on the bottom "_Count | Value 4 | Type unsigned int" "_First2 " Any idea what my issue is? note: ignore the bad4dogs thats supposed to be another comparison once I had the good working

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 28;
const int ARRAY_SIZE2 = 20;
const int sixFoods = 6;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int quit = 1;
string good4dogs[ARRAY_SIZE];
string bad4dogs[ARRAY_SIZE2];
string userFoodNames[sixFoods];
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;

ifstream inputFile;
ifstream inputFile2;


inputFile.open("GoodForDogs.txt");
inputFile2.open("PoisonForDogs.txt");

if (inputFile)
{
    cout << "it worked";
}
else
{
    cout << "error";
}

while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> good4dogs[count])
    count++;

while (count2 < ARRAY_SIZE2 && inputFile2 >> bad4dogs[count2])
    count2++;

inputFile.close();


cout << "Please enter up to six foods." << endl << endl;

for (int k = 0; k < sixFoods; k++)
{
  cout << "Food " << (k + 1) << ": ";
  getline(cin, userFoodNames[k]);
}

cout << "Foods that YOU have that also match food GOOD for dogs.\n";
cout << "-------------------------------------------------------\n";
while (i < ARRAY_SIZE && j < sixFoods) do
{
    if (good4dogs[i] == userFoodNames[j])
    {
        cout << good4dogs[i] << endl;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if (good4dogs[i] > userFoodNames[j])
        j++;
    else
        i++;
} while ( quit == 1);
```

Comment: while ( quit == 1);  is an interesting condition.

Comment: Are you sure you actually read `ARRAY_SIZE` lines into `good4dogs` If that stops to early you get interesting results. Print `count` after the first while loop.

Comment: The elephant in the room is named [`std::vector`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @user4581301 I have to use arrays for this assignment.

Comment: Learn to love the debugger.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't understand why, in this day and age, courses don't start off by showing usage of the debugger, starting with the simple "Hello World".  What could be more of a learning tool than actually seeing your variables change values, how loops flow, etc.?  It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the state of the affairs in Computer Science education is trully terrible. It is usually taught by incompenent people who have no clue of a proper programming. This is just one of the examples.

Comment: Admittedly this was a while ago, but the professor who convinced me to transfer from Computer Science to Engineering told the class, "If you wrote your code right there would be no bugs." in response to "What about debugging?"

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 1):

Writing the problem code out better, you get

```
while (i < ARRAY_SIZE && j < sixFoods) 
{
    do
    {
        if (good4dogs[i] == userFoodNames[j])
        {
            cout << good4dogs[i] << endl;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (good4dogs[i] > userFoodNames[j])
            j++;
        else
            i++;
    } while ( quit == 1); 
}
```

Which shows that there are two loops in play here.

The outer loop will guard against `i` and `j` overrunning their respective buffers, but will not make any bounds tests until after the inner loop completes.

The inner loop will never complete because `quit` is never set to anything but 1. This leads to a infinite loop and nothing to stop `i` and `j` from going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your last loop is a while do { } while :-) It's probably the source of your issue as it will only stop if quit != 1.

Another problem that you have is that your arrays are not sorted, which will make your last loop fail. Anyway, in C++, to compute the intersection, using set_intersection algorithm is probably a better solution: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

Globally, you are more writing C than C++ code. You should prefer the usage of std::vector rather than C-style arrays. You should also prefer using algorithms rather than loop.

Something like:

```
vector<string> good4dogs;
ifstream inputFile("Good4Dogs.txt");
copy(istream_iterator<string>(inputFile), {}, back_inserter(good4dogs));
```

allows you to read the content of the file in a vector without the problems you have consisting of hard coded limit on your vector, needing to handle smaller files etc...

Note that you are checking validity of and closing inputFile but not inputFile2

Answer (score 0):

```
inputFile.open("GoodForDogs.txt");
inputFile2.open("PoisonForDogs.txt");

if (inputFile)
{
    cout << "it worked";
}
else
{
    cout << "error";
}
```

First, you haven't checked on the second file, and in case of "error" your program will just read the file just as if there was no "error". Aside from how the message "it worked" is contradictory, because it hasn't read the file yet.

To fix this, assuming you're working inside `main`, you replace it with something like this..

```
if (!inputFile || !inputFile2)
{
    cout << "error: could not open files.";
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> good4dogs[count])
    count++;

while (count2 < ARRAY_SIZE2 && inputFile2 >> bad4dogs[count2])
    count2++;

inputFile.close();
```

Here you need to add `close` for the second file.

---

```
while (i < ARRAY_SIZE && j < sixFoods) do
{
    if (good4dogs[i] == userFoodNames[j])
    {
        cout << good4dogs[i] << endl;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if (good4dogs[i] > userFoodNames[j])
        j++;
    else
        i++;
}
while (quit == 1);
```

Here `while (quit == 1)` is an infinite loop, since quit is initialized as `1` and is not updated inside the loop.